# react native why I cant scroll on my modal

Tags: react-native, expo

I need your help. I want to add a scrollview into a swipeable Modal. The problem is now that I cant scroll. Can anyone help me to fix it ?

```
      <Modal 
        statusBarTranslucent
        isVisible={modal}
        swipeDirection="down"
        onSwipeComplete={() => closeModal()}
        swipeThreshold={20}
        backdropTransitionOutTiming={0}
      >
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', borderRadius: 6, padding: 6, borderWidth: 2}}>
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, color: 'black', textAlign: 'center'}}>Test Data</Text>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <Text>Test</Text>
              <TextInput placeholder="Test" />
            </View>
            <Text>Test2</Text>
            <Text>Test3</Text>
            <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="120" keyboardType="numeric" />
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        </View>
      </Modal>
```

.........................................

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing this issue as well. Found a workaround for now.

```
<Modal> 
  <ScrollView> 
    <TouchableOpacity> ... </TouchableOpacity>
  </ScrollView>
<Modal>
```